# SQL get Values where some is greater than value with Having not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, having

I have this code:

```
Select firstname, lastname, sum(quantity) as quantitySum
FROM Customer
JOIN "Order"
ON Customer.id = "Order".customerid
JOIN orderitem
ON "Order".id = orderitem.orderid
WHERE country = 'Germany'
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
HAVING quantitySum > 500
ORDER BY lastname
```

But it gives me an error. I can not figure it out. Happy for every help!

Comment: `HAVING sum(quantity) > 500`?

Comment: Clarify which RDBMS you're using and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Having` clause execute after `group by` and then `select` so you have to use aggregated function with `having` as following

```
Select firstname, lastname, sum(quantity) as quantitySum
FROM Customer
JOIN "Order"
ON Customer.id = "Order".customerid
JOIN orderitem
ON "Order".id = orderitem.orderid
WHERE country = 'Germany'
GROUP BY firstname, lastname
HAVING sum(quantity) > 500
ORDER BY lastname
```